# Why does my computer hibernate when it sleeps?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, sleep-wake, bug

I am MacBook Pro w/ Retina, Mid-2014, running macOS Sierra 10.12.1.

About 2/3 of the time my computer times out and goes to sleep, the screen goes blank as normal, but tries to wake it don't work. Can move mouse, but screen is black, can't click, can't press a key, etc. The only way to tempfix that I know is closing and reopening the screen. Then, everything returns to normal.

I noticed other topics similar to this, but I do not believe it works eventually as other topics say. Might be wrong though.

Comment: I cannot find that setting anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried resetting the SMC?

Here’s what you do for your particular model of MacBook Pro:

1. Shut down your computer
2. Keep the power cable **plugged in**.
3. Press at the **same time** <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>control</kbd> (on the left side of the keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
4. Let go
5. Turn your computer back on with the power button.

You can read more info about this on Apple's article about when you might want to try an SMC reset:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295